# How to get post category name in a wp-query->have_posts loop (the string only)

Tags: wordpress, templates

I want to get the string only `post_category_name` for each post in a while `WP_Query()->have_posts()` loop. e.g.: the following.

```
<?php while (WP_Query()->have_posts()) : ?>

    <div class="post_category_name"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

How do i get the category name for the loop, string only, without any element wrapping so i can use it as a `class="category"`.

I've tried `the_category()` but it returns a `li > a` item...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somebody already though about it. You're looking for the [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) function.

Doing:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Should give you, for example:

```
<div id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-one category-two tag-one tag-two">
```

EDIT:

If you want only the category name, then you have to specify witch category you need, as posts can have more than one. Apart from loop searches and verifications, if you want the first one, you would do:

```
$c = get_the_category();
// Name
echo $c[0]->cat_name;
// Slug
echo $c[0]->category_nicename;
```

Comment: thanks but this isn't quite what i'm looking for, just need the category_name not 'category-%name%', so i can use it elsewhere it the loop not just the class.

Comment: @devric Edited the answer for this case.

Comment: @devric It's far more recommended to follow the standards of the platform you're working on. You can always be sure that `post_class()` will work as specified.

Comment: What if i need all categories that the post has?